# Free/Open Source resx files with Standard Phrases

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, resx

I was wondering if there are any free/OS resx files for phrases commonly used among websites. For instance, we all use save/submit/retry/cancel/etc. and I'd be surprised if there wasn't a library out there with these standard phrases in multiple languages. I searched but came up empty...Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is for words and phrases used in Microsoft products. See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688105.aspx

If you use their online glossary and terminology search tool, you'll be able to discover that *"Do you really want to exit?"* is *"Ydych chi wir am fynd allan?"* in Welsh and *"Viltu örugglega hætta?"* in Icelandic.

Alternatively if you have an MSDN subscription you can download the specific glossaries.